# How can I ensure that my app's data doesn't get deleted when releasing an update?

Tags: java, android

My android app saves an array of Objects to cache using serializable, but when updates are released, the array is completely deleted and users have to re-do all input. What is the solution to this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you should look on the android development wiki / help section for saving data between updates. If your problem is *reading saved inputs*, then that is very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you store you serializable object to the cache? The package management system will keep the old data for an update installation of the app.

```
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
    try {
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                getCacheDir() + File.separator + "object"));
        MyObject object = new MyObject();
        object.setData(15);
        object.setName("name");
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(new MyObject());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (objectOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                objectOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm saving the objects to internal storage, so maybe that is why they're lost after an update? Should I just switch to external? Thanks

Comment: Android will keep the old data for an updating installation. It won't delete the data, even the cache. But switching to external storage will be more safe.

Answer (score 0):

Look into ActiveAndroid if you are fine with storing data on the device. Look into building out a restful API in the cloud if you want it to persist forever.